# Proof that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,-a]$ and $[-a,0]$ then it is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,0]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving uniform continuity on an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80889/proving-uniform-continuity-on-an-interval)

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,-a]$ and $[-a,0]$, then it is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,0]$ where $a\in(0,\infty)$.

**Proof:**

From the definition of uniform continuity we have that:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta_1: \forall x,y \in(-\infty,-a] : |x-y|\lt \delta_1: |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

and

$$ \forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta_2: \forall x,y \in [-a,0]: |x-y|< \delta_2 : |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

If we take $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ then we have that:

If $x,y\in(-\infty,-a]$ then $|x-y|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

If $x,y\in[-a,0]$ then $|x-y|< \delta\rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

If $x\in(-\infty,-a]$ and $y\in[-a,0]$ then we have that as $\delta>|x-y|>|x-(-a)|$ and $\delta>|x-y|>|y-(-a)|$

from the uniform continuity of $f$ on $(-\infty,-a]$ and $[-a,0]$ we have that 
$$
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)| &= |f(x)-f(-a)+f(-a)-f(y)|
\\ &< |f(x)-f(-a)|+|f(y)-f(-a)| < 
\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon .
\end{align*}
$$

Is the above correct? Thanks for any help!

So we have that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Correct, up to a few misprints and omissions.  Can you find them?

Comment: Aside from lack of proper punctuation and  a few deltas, yes.

Comment: Cool thanks very much, is that any better?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80889/proving-uniform-continuity-on-an-interval/80907#80907 :)